# How to configure the title of Alert Dialogue

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-activity

I am trying to change the text colour and font of title "Enter Details" which you can see in   below snapshot but was not able to make it. Please help me to solve this problem.

**Code:-**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button cust;
Dialog custom;
EditText Fname;
EditText Lname;
TextView txt;
Button savebtn;
Button canbtn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cust = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cusdia);
        txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
        cust.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            String fname,lname;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                custom = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                custom.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

                Fname = (EditText)custom.findViewById(R.id.fname);
                Lname = (EditText)custom.findViewById(R.id.lname);
                savebtn = (Button)custom.findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
                canbtn = (Button)custom.findViewById(R.id.canbtn);
                custom.setTitle("Enter Details");

                savebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        fname = Fname.getText().toString();
                        lname = Lname.getText().toString();

                        txt.setText("Your Name is "+fname +lname);
                        custom.dismiss();
                    }

                });
```

**ALert Dialogue box Snapshot**

[image: ALert Dialogue box]

Comment: you have to make your own style sheet for that or if there is the font size or text color avaliable then you can change it in xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following code in **`style.xml`**

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

     <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">#ff4444</item>

</style>
```

**`and set your dialog like following`**

```
d = new Dialog(Inquiry.this,R.style.MyDialog);
```

I am sure , you will get what you want.

Comment: Thanks , Finally I am able to resolve this problem. Thanks alot!! :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use below code.create custom dialog using xml file and avoid default title bar. instead of default title bar you can use textview in xml file.and also use below style in java code.

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DetailsActivity.this, R.style.FullHeightDialog);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.insert_text_dialog);
```

style

```
<style name="FullHeightDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use

```
     new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setCustomTitle(customTitleView)
```

and for `customTitleView` create a `view` for example a `TextView` and set the `font` and `color` for it.